# How to shift opacity via i in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I was trying to make an to-Top button, well, after a few pix scroll, let us say 1000, it will show up. That is a popular button I suppose these days.

Anyhow, it worked and I d like to add a shifting opacity property to the element after it show up, I observed a few websites, and one of them use some algorithm to shift it from 0 to 1, I d like to make it simple as I do not know much about algorithm, so below is my code.

```
if(navbarScroll > 1000){
    toTopEle.style.visibility = "visible";
    toTopEle.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
    for(var i = 0; i < 1; i += 0.1){
        toTopEle.style.opacity = "i";
    };
};
```

Anyhow, after the event, it did not work, and there even isn't an opacity property on the element at all.

So, what is wrong here?

btw, if you are so kind to give an solution, plz no JQuery, I am learning pure js :)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `"i"` is literally "i". If you want to assign the number in the `i` variable, get rid of the quotes.

Comment: Do you realize you set opacity to a string "i", not to the variable's value? Another problem is that it's not updated until script is finished executing, you need to use setInterval() to get animated fadeout/fadein effects

Comment: `toTopEle.style.opacity = i;`

Comment: just remove `""` quotes from i while you assign it to opacity like `toTopEle.style.opacity = i;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments state, this will be the correct syntax

```
toTopEle.style.opacity = i;
```

however the efftect will probably not be what you wish? It will probalby be faded in an instance, instead of over time. You need a timer to fade it slowly, or a css animation